# codeigniter photo upload in signup form

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

[image: logo]

When i Upload a photo its adding to the database but the photo is not coming inside the folder. After many attempts I could not take photo inside the photo folder. So please do the code you need to upload the photo and take it inside the photo folder. I will be forever grateful to you. Correct the new code by associating it with this code. Thank you...

**View**

```
<form method="post" action="provider_join" id="wizard">
    <h4 class="text-center mb-4">Company Information</h4>
    <div class="default-form contact-form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="comname" placeholder="Your Company Name" required>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="tele" placeholder="Your Telephone Number" required>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="email" name="emailid" placeholder="Your Email Address" required>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" name="confirmpassword" placeholder="Confirm Password" required>
        </div
    </div>

    <div class="dropzone-wrapper">
        <div class="dropzone-desc">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"></i>
            <p>Choose an image file or drag it here.</p>
        </div>
        <input type="file" name="photo" class="dropzone">
    </div>
</form>
```

**Controllar**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
Class Provider_Join extends CI_Controller {

        public function index(){
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('comname','Company Name','required|alpha');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('tele','Telephone','required|alpha');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('emailid','Email id','required|valid_email|is_unique[tblpv.emailId]');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','required|min_length[6]');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('confirmpassword','Confirm Password','required|min_length[6]|matches[password]');

                if($this->form_validation->run()){
                $comname=$this->input->post('comname');
                $tele=$this->input->post('tele');
                $emailid=$this->input->post('emailid');
                $password=$this->input->post('password');
                $photo=$this->input->post('photo');
                $status=1;
                $this->load->model('Provider_Join_Model');
                $this->Provider_Join_Model->insert($comname,$tele,$emailid,$password,$photo,$status);
                } else {
                $this->load->view('user/provider_join');
                }       
        }
}
```

**Models**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
Class Provider_Join_Model extends CI_Model{

    public function insert($comname,$tele,$emailid,$password,$photo,$status){
$data=array(
            'comname'=>$comname,
            'tele'=>$tele,
            'emailId'=>$emailid,
            'userPassword'=>$password,
            'photo'=>$photo,
            'isActive'=>$status
        );
$sql_query=$this->db->insert('tblpv',$data);
if($sql_query){
$this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Registration successfull');
        redirect('user/provider_join');
    }
    else{
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Somthing went worng. Error!!');
        redirect('user/provider_join');
    }

    }
}
```

Comment: Ok for a starter , You need to be using `<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`.. However, i cant see the logic for handling uploaded files

Comment: But how do I get inside the photo folder?

Comment: Uploaded file is not accessible via `$this->input->post()`. Use [upload file library](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html) instead

Comment: I tried my best but could not